# Flask and SQL Server Query via PYODBC - returning only 1 record instead of multiple (for loop)

Tags: python, for-loop, flask, pyodbc

I have Flask running. I am making a query to SQL server using PYODBC.

Instead of returning multiple records, I am getting only 1.

My loop is meant to return more than 1 - if I print the records (postcode and dma) outside of Flask (normal py script), I get many records printed.

Is it a Flask issue? Or am I using the wrong Loop?

```
from flask import Flask
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:xxxx,xxx;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=300;')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()


    app= Flask(__name__)
    
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        cursor.execute("QUERY GOES HERE")
        row = cursor.fetchone() 
        while row: 
            return(row.postalcode+'||'+row.dma)
            row = cursor.fetchone()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Comment: instead of using `row = cursor.fetchone()` use `row = cursor.fetchall()`

Comment: for row in cursor.fetchall():
  return(row.postalcode)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)

The above didn't work - pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')

Answer (score 0):

Use `fetchall` instead it will fetch all the rows. `fetchone` only fetches the first one

```py
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row.postalcode+'||'+row.dma)
```